# Properly managing Erlang concurrency

Tags: multithreading, erlang

I'm putting together some Erlang code with the following process:

```
- Spawn a number of threads
- Each thread scans an IP address
- Report back to the main thread the results
```

I've got the main thread running this:

```
cve_receive() ->
    receive
    Msg ->
            io:fwrite("~s~n", [Msg]),
            cve_receive()
    after 5000 ->
            ok
    end.
```

It's functionally correct and receives what it's meant to receive, but I'm not really sure how to properly manage the exit condition. It currently just sits on a timeout, but the reality is that all threads usually finish in 100ms or so, which means there's a pointless timeout in this picture. Really what it should say is "after all threads terminate".

Is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to create a barrier by keeping a counter in `cve_receive` so you can keep track of how many worker processes that have completed.

Something like:

```
%% First Spawn N work processes
...
%% Then receive N messages.
cve_receive(N).
...
cve_receive(N) ->
    receive
        Msg ->
           io:fwrite("~s~n", [Msg]),
           case N == 1 of
              true  -> all_done;
              false -> cve_receive(N-1)
           end;
        after 5000 ->
           {timeout, N}
    end.
```

If you need to perform some cleanup in the case processes don't finish within the timeout interval you could store a list of process id's instead of the counter. 
Remove the pid on receiving the message and on timeout you can e.g. kill all the processes remaining in the list.

EDIT: If worker processes crash the simple solution above would still work, since you would get a timeout eventually. But you can use the [monitor/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2) function and handle the `DOWN` message in your `cve_receive` function.

Comment: Many thanks! Aside from hoping I wouldn't have to carry that variable around, I have been letting threads just raise exceptions in places and I didn't want that to deadlock when counting to N. monitor/2 is a great help.

Comment: An alternative to `monitor` is `spawn_link` (or just `link`), depends on what you want to achieve. LYSE has a good discussion about these: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-processes

Answer (score 1):

To make @johlo's answer a bit more idiomatic:

```
cve_receive(0) ->
  all_done;
cve_receive(N) ->
  receive
    Msg ->
       io:fwrite("~s~n", [Msg]),
       cve_receive(N-1)
    after 5000 ->
      {timeout, N}
  end.
```